# For any finite subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have that $\left| \frac{A+A}{A+A}\right| \gg |A|^2 $

Tags: nt.number-theory, na.numerical-analysis, harmonic-analysis, additive-combinatorics

I am trying to understand how sumset theory is actually used in other parts of math or within additive combinatorics.  Here are some results I have found in this paper from 2018 ([[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.10842)], [[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5775)]):

- **Thm** (Balog, 2015) For any finite subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have that $\left| \frac{A+A}{A+A}\right| \gg |A|^2 $.
- **Thm** (Roche-Newton, 2015) For  $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ finite, we have $|(A \pm A)(A \pm A) \gg \frac{|A|^2}{\log |A|}$.
- **Thm** (Li, 2010) For any finite subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have that $ |A+A|^2 |A/A| \gg |A|^4 $.

I am wondering how results like this are connected to more traditional branches of Real Analysis.  Parts of this paper ask for "small doubling"

- $|A+A| \leq |A|^{1 + \epsilon} $ if $\epsilon$ were zero, this would be an arithmetic progression $A = a \mathbb{Z}+b$.  Then I wonder what subsets with $\epsilon \ll 1$ should behave like. Are these [approximate groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_group) with $G = \mathbb{R}$?
- There seems to be a version of the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). $$E⁺(A) = \big| \{ a_1 + a_2 = a_3 + a_4 : a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, \in \mathbb{A} \} \big| \geq \frac{|A|^4}{|A+A|} $$
  Generically, the number of solutions is $|A|^2$ unless there are a lot of coincidences.

How do these results compare to other branches of analysis?  I am currently looking through these notes of [Gowers](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/greenbj/papers/addcomb2009-4.pdf).  From what I've seen these sumset problems quickly turn into questions in geometry or harmonic analysis.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. There are many connections between sumset-type results and analysis and geometry, especially in using techniques from the latter to solve sumset problems. You seem to be asking for a general overview of the area, which is best gotten from lecture notes (such as those of Gowers you mention) or a textbook (such as Tao and Vu's Additive Combinatorics).

Comment: In particular the title of your question is just quoting the result of Balog. Do you have a specific question relating to this result and/or its proof?